# Showing timer in my tableview cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm showing Countdown timer in my Tableview cells for every product, having limited time offers.

As i scroll my tableview the values of timer are reflected to other cells. I know it is due to reuse of table view cells.

I want to show countdown timer for each product which are continuously changing for each product.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: put some code for understand .

Comment: Atleast show us some code so that we can correct what you did wrong

Answer (score 0):

You need to add observer in awakeFromNib() of your custom tableview cell class with a target function which update your UI of the cell. Then you need to declare a NSTimer variable inside your ViewController with target function which post the notification in regular intervals .You can set the initial values in cellForRowAtIndexPath method of the tableview.